# How I can create new user in GeoServer by GOT (npmjs) through GeoServer RESTful API?

Tags: geoserver-rest-api

This is my code. I'm going to create new user by GOT (npmjs) and POST method in GeoServer 2.17.1 But, it can't create new user. Can someone tell me where I made mistake in my code?

```
  (async() => {
        try {
            const { body } = await got.post('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/users/', {
                //Geoserver Username and Password
                username: "admin",
                password: "@dmin9901",
                //Headers
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                    "Content-type": "application/json",


                },

                //New Username and password

                data: {
                    "userName": "test",
                    "password": "test",
                    "enabled": true
                }


            }).json()
            console.log(body);


        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.response);
            //=> 'Internal server error ...'

        }
        //=> {hello: 'world'}
    })();
```

it return:

```
<ref *2> IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: [],
    flowing: false,
    ended: true,
    endEmitted: true,
    reading: false,
    sync: false,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: true,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: false,
    destroyed: false,
    errored: false,
    closed: false,
    closeEmitted: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    awaitDrainWriters: null,
    multiAwaitDrain: false,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null,
    [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
  },
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    end: [Function: responseOnEnd],
    error: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function (anonymous)] },
    aborted: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function (anonymous)] },
    readable: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  _eventsCount: 4,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  socket: <ref *1> Socket {
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: 'localhost',
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: true,
      ended: true,
      endEmitted: true,
      reading: false,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: false,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: true,
      errored: false,
      closed: true,
      closeEmitted: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      end: [Array],
      free: [Function: onFree],
      close: [Array],
      timeout: [Function: onTimeout],
      agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
      error: [Function: socketErrorListener],
      data: [Function: socketOnData],
      drain: [Function: ondrain],
      connect: [Function]
    },
    _eventsCount: 9,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: true,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: true,
      ended: true,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: true,
      decodeStrings: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: false,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 1,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      errored: false,
      closed: true,
      writable: true
    },
    allowHalfOpen: false,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: null,
    _server: null,
    parser: null,
    _httpMessage: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 10,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [Circular *1],
      _header: 'POST /geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/users/ HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'user-agent: got (https://github.com/sindresorhus/got)\r\n' +
        'access-control-allow-origin: *\r\n' +
        'accept: application/json\r\n' +
        'content-type: application/json\r\n' +
        'content-length: 52\r\n' +
        'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'Host: localhost:8080\r\n' +
        'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46JTQwZG1pbjk5MDE=\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/users/',
      _ended: true,
      res: [Circular *2],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'localhost',
      protocol: 'http:',
      timings: [Object],
      emit: [Function (anonymous)],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(reentry)]: true
    },
    _peername: { address: '127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv4', port: 8080 },
    write: [Function: writeAfterFIN],
    [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 264,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: null,
    [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 299,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 400
  },
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: true,
  headers: {
    connection: 'close',
    'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'set-cookie': [
      'remember-me=;Path=/geoserver;Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT;Max-Age=0'
    ],
    'www-authenticate': 'Basic realm="GeoServer Realm"',
    'cache-control': 'must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store',
    server: 'Jetty(9.4.18.v20190429)'
  },
  rawHeaders: [
    'Connection',
    'close',
    'X-Frame-Options',
    'SAMEORIGIN',
    'Set-Cookie',
    'remember-me=;Path=/geoserver;Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT;Max-Age=0',
    'WWW-Authenticate',
    'Basic realm="GeoServer Realm"',
    'Cache-Control',
    'must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store',
    'Server',
    'Jetty(9.4.18.v20190429)'
  ],
  trailers: {},
  rawTrailers: [],
  aborted: false,
  upgrade: false,
  url: 'http://admin:%40dmin9901@localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/users/',
  method: null,
  statusCode: 401,
  statusMessage: 'Unauthorized',
  client: <ref *1> Socket {
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: 'localhost',
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: true,
      ended: true,
      endEmitted: true,
      reading: false,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: false,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: true,
      errored: false,
      closed: true,
      closeEmitted: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      end: [Array],
      free: [Function: onFree],
      close: [Array],
      timeout: [Function: onTimeout],
      agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
      error: [Function: socketErrorListener],
      data: [Function: socketOnData],
      drain: [Function: ondrain],
      connect: [Function]
    },
    _eventsCount: 9,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: true,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: true,
      ended: true,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: true,
      decodeStrings: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: false,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 1,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      errored: false,
      closed: true,
      writable: true
    },
    allowHalfOpen: false,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: null,
    _server: null,
    parser: null,
    _httpMessage: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 10,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [Circular *1],
      _header: 'POST /geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/users/ HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'user-agent: got (https://github.com/sindresorhus/got)\r\n' +
        'access-control-allow-origin: *\r\n' +
        'accept: application/json\r\n' +
        'content-type: application/json\r\n' +
        'content-length: 52\r\n' +
        'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'Host: localhost:8080\r\n' +
        'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46JTQwZG1pbjk5MDE=\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/users/',
      _ended: true,
      res: [Circular *2],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'localhost',
      protocol: 'http:',
      timings: [Object],
      emit: [Function (anonymous)],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(reentry)]: true
    },
    _peername: { address: '127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv4', port: 8080 },
    write: [Function: writeAfterFIN],
    [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 264,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: null,
    [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 299,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 400
  },
  _consuming: true,
  _dumped: false,
  req: <ref *3> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      abort: [Function],
      error: [Array],
      close: [Function],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      continue: [Function (anonymous)],
      information: [Function (anonymous)],
      upgrade: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 10,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: null,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    socket: <ref *1> Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'localhost',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 9,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: null,
      _server: null,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *3],
      _peername: [Object],
      write: [Function: writeAfterFIN],
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 264,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: null,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 299,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 400
    },
    _header: 'POST /geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/users/ HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'user-agent: got (https://github.com/sindresorhus/got)\r\n' +
      'access-control-allow-origin: *\r\n' +
      'accept: application/json\r\n' +
      'content-type: application/json\r\n' +
      'content-length: 52\r\n' +
      'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\n' +
      'Host: localhost:8080\r\n' +
      'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46JTQwZG1pbjk5MDE=\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 80,
      protocol: 'http:',
      options: [Object],
      requests: {},
      sockets: [Object],
      freeSockets: {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'fifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'POST',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    path: '/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/users/',
    _ended: true,
    res: [Circular *2],
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'localhost',
    protocol: 'http:',
    timings: {
      start: 1597219675880,
      socket: 1597219675883,
      lookup: 1597219675886,
      connect: 1597219675888,
      secureConnect: undefined,
      upload: 1597219675888,
      response: 1597219676023,
      end: 1597219676028,
      error: undefined,
      abort: undefined,
      phases: [Object]
    },
    emit: [Function (anonymous)],
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      'user-agent': [Array],
      'access-control-allow-origin': [Array],
      accept: [Array],
      'content-type': [Array],
      'content-length': [Array],
      'accept-encoding': [Array],
      host: [Array],
      authorization: [Array]
    },
    [Symbol(reentry)]: true
  },
  timings: {
    start: 1597219675880,
    socket: 1597219675883,
    lookup: 1597219675886,
    connect: 1597219675888,
    secureConnect: undefined,
    upload: 1597219675888,
    response: 1597219676023,
    end: 1597219676028,
    error: undefined,
    abort: undefined,
    phases: {
      wait: 3,
      dns: 3,
      tcp: 2,
      tls: undefined,
      request: 0,
      firstByte: 135,
      download: 5,
      total: 148
    }
  },
  emit: [Function (anonymous)],
  requestUrl: 'http://admin:%40dmin9901@localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/users/',
  redirectUrls: [],
  request: PromisableRequest {
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 0,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: false,
      ended: true,
      endEmitted: true,
      reading: false,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: false,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: true,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      destroyed: true,
      errored: false,
      closed: true,
      closeEmitted: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      pipe: [Array],
      unpipe: [Function (anonymous)],
      response: [Function (anonymous)],
      request: [Function (anonymous)],
      redirect: [Function (anonymous)],
      uploadProgress: [Function (anonymous)],
      downloadProgress: [Function (anonymous)],
      resume: [Function (anonymous)],
      pause: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function: onclose],
      end: [Function: onend],
      finish: [Function: onfinish],
      error: [Array],
      close: [Function: onclose],
      readable: [Function: bound onReadable]
    },
    _eventsCount: 15,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 0,
      finalCalled: true,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: true,
      ended: true,
      finished: true,
      destroyed: true,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: true,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: false,
      closed: true
    },
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    requestInitialized: true,
    redirects: [],
    _progressCallbacks: [],
    write: [Function: onLockedWrite],
    end: [Function: onLockedWrite],
    options: {
      method: 'POST',
      retry: [Object],
      headers: [Object],
      hooks: [Object],
      cache: undefined,
      dnsCache: undefined,
      decompress: true,
      throwHttpErrors: true,
      followRedirect: true,
      isStream: false,
      responseType: 'json',
      resolveBodyOnly: false,
      maxRedirects: 10,
      prefixUrl: [Getter/Setter],
      methodRewriting: true,
      ignoreInvalidCookies: false,
      http2: false,
      allowGetBody: false,
      https: undefined,
      pagination: [Object],
      parseJson: [Function: parseJson],
      stringifyJson: [Function: stringifyJson],
      username: 'admin',
      password: '@dmin9901',
      url: [URL],
      request: undefined,
      timeout: {},
      agent: undefined,
      [Symbol(isNormalizedAlready)]: true,
      [Symbol(request)]: [Function: request]
    },
    requestUrl: 'http://admin:%40dmin9901@localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/users/',
    _cannotHaveBody: false,
    _noPipe: true,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(downloadedSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(uploadedSize)]: 52,
    [Symbol(serverResponsesPiped)]: Set(0) {},
    [Symbol(stopReading)]: true,
    [Symbol(triggerRead)]: true,
    [Symbol(jobs)]: [],
    [Symbol(body)]: '{"userName":"test","password":"test","enabled":true}',
    [Symbol(bodySize)]: 52,
    [Symbol(cancelTimeouts)]: [Function: cancelTimeouts],
    [Symbol(unproxyEvents)]: [Function (anonymous)],
    [Symbol(request)]: <ref *3> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 10,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [Socket],
      _header: 'POST /geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/users/ HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'user-agent: got (https://github.com/sindresorhus/got)\r\n' +
        'access-control-allow-origin: *\r\n' +
        'accept: application/json\r\n' +
        'content-type: application/json\r\n' +
        'content-length: 52\r\n' +
        'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'Host: localhost:8080\r\n' +
        'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46JTQwZG1pbjk5MDE=\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/geoserver/rest/security/usergroup/users/',
      _ended: true,
      res: [Circular *2],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'localhost',
      protocol: 'http:',
      timings: [Object],
      emit: [Function (anonymous)],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(reentry)]: true
    },
    [Symbol(originalResponse)]: [Circular *2],
    [Symbol(isFromCache)]: false,
    [Symbol(responseSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(response)]: [Circular *2]
  },
  isFromCache: false,
  ip: '127.0.0.1',
  retryCount: 0,
  rawBody: <Buffer >,
  body: '',
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

Comment: We need to see the data being sent to GeoServer, it's reply and the relevant section of the log file

Comment: I add return value to my question

Comment: @IanTurton it seem due to a bug in GeoServer REST api, because I can create new user if I change from json form to xml format, I think this would be an old bug inherited from version 2.15

Comment: Then you will need to open a ticket